# Windows 11 changed Finnish date format to not include weekday, now my batch scripts won't work

Tags: batch, batch-file, windows-11, date-time, date

I have this script that relies on getting the current day of the week from the command line..

```
if "%date:~0,2%"=="ma" set "weekday=true" & set "hangday=false"
if "%date:~0,2%"=="ti" set "weekday=true" & set "hangday=false"
if "%date:~0,2%"=="ke" set "weekday=true" & set "hangday=false"
if "%date:~0,2%"=="to" set "weekday=true" & set "hangday=false"
if "%date:~0,2%"=="pe" set "weekday=true" & set "hangday=true"
if "%date:~0,2%"=="la" set "weekday=false" & set "bhours=false" & set "hangday=true"
if "%date:~0,2%"=="su" set "weekday=false" & set "bhours=false" & set "hangday=false" & set "selfday=true"
```

Those `ma ti ke to pe la su` are the days of the week in Finnish. This worked on Windows 10 when the format for `%date%` was the correct `to 22.11.2022`. Now in Windows 11 it's just `22/11/2022` which is all sorts of wrong, and I don't even get a single choice with day names. The long date would allow me to set days as names but I'm not aware how to use that at prompt. Is there a trick I could use? I am hoping I can continue using English language in Windows 11. Everything else is set to Finnish. Regional formats says `English (Finland)` with no other Finnish option either.

Comment: Please clarify your question. What have you set as your region and language? What is your date format in Windows? How do you get Finnish day names when using English?

Comment: "This worked on Windows 10 but not on Windows 10" erm this cannot be right ...

Comment: Not sure to what the problem is, but can't you [change the date format in your whole PC](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/change-date-format-in-windows-11.8460/) - to what it was before in Windows 10, I mean?

Comment: @Sylvain That customize date format box certainly fixed the issue, under additional settings. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not happy with the default Windows 11 date format, you simply can change it systemwide to what it was before in Windows 10 (and before).

Procedure: [for example](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/change-date-format-in-windows-11.8460/).

Comment: @Sylvain - You should quote and cite the relevant information from your external source preventing your answer from being a sign post.

Comment: When it's just a page to follow, and I don't have 15 minutes to make an proper Answer on it, it's easier this way. But I understand, I take note.

Comment: Answers that only contain a link are not help, I provided feedback to help you write better answers, but you failed to address something that would have taken only a few moments to address.